# How to send and verify OTP using cloud function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, api, google-cloud-functions, one-time-password

I have API to send and verify otp code. I need to link that API to my flutter app using Firebase clod function. How is it possible Please help ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Setup firebase cloud function [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/how-to-start-with-flutter-firebase-and-cloud-functions-1d1aa38c4d82)
2. Your js code be like

   ```
   exports.sendOtp = functions.https.onCall((request, response) => {
         const options = JSON.stringify({
           mobile: request.text,
         });
         const headers = {
           "Authorization": "Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx”,
         };
         const res = axios.post(“url”, options, {headers: headers}).then((response) => {
           console.log(response);
           return response;
         });
         return res.statusCode;
       });
   ```
3. Your service code be like

```
    Future<void> sendOtp(String mobile) async {
        HttpsCallable callable =
            FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('sendOtp');
        final resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
          'text': mobile,
        });
     }
```